# Sending a message to the Telegram channel using Python

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events

import os
import random
import time

print('User-Bot started') 

api_id = api hash

api_hash = 'api id'

with TelegramClient('anonimal', api_id, api_hash) as client:
    while True:
        mem = open('C:/fg/spam/members.csv') # I take the ID of the chat from the members.csv file
-100972139773
        line = mem.readline()
        print(line)
        client.send_message(line, 'hello chat')
        print('message send')

client.run_until_disconnected()
```

> Error: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\drago\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\crash.py",
> line 21, in 
> client.send_message(line, 'Сколько стоит переносной ларек?')   File
> "C:\Users\drago\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\sync.py",
> line 39, in syncified
> return loop.run_until_complete(coro)   File "C:\Users\drago\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py",
> line 649, in run_until_complete
> return future.result()   File "C:\Users\drago\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\messages.py",
> line 838, in send_message
> entity = await self.get_input_entity(entity)   File "C:\Users\drago\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py",
> line 438, in get_input_entity
> await self._get_entity_from_string(peer))   File "C:\Users\drago\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py",
> line 575, in _get_entity_from_string
> raise ValueError( ValueError: Cannot find any entity corresponding to "-100972139773"

After entering the data, this error occurs.

Comment: dont send id as string must be number `-100972139773`

Answer (score 0):

You need to save it in the cache before use, or use a username instead. `user_id` must be an int.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, this happens in case your account is not a member of the channel, so please check that account you are using is a member of the channel of your interest. Also, using `with client` and `while True` is considered a bad practice, please [read doc](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/) and use the more appropriate approach if you want to listen to something indefently:

```
client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

and don't forget to disconnect when you are done, using:

```
client.disconnect()
```